# How can I copy a directory, overwriting its contents if it exists using Powershell?

Tags: windows-7, powershell

I have a directory Source with some files in it, which I would like to copy to a folder Destination. Destination may exist, and it may have files in it already. Any files with the same name as those in Source should be overwritten.

If I run this in Powershell:

```
Copy-Item Source Destination -Force -Recurse
Copy-Item Source Destination -Force -Recurse
Copy-Item Source Destination -Force -Recurse
```

Then the first line creates the folder `.\Destination` and copies `.\Source` into it, which is what I'd like to repeat for the next time. However, the second line copies `.\Source` into the new `.\Destination` folder (creating `.\Destination\Source`) instead, then the third line overwrites `.\Destination\Source` again.

How can I make it act like in the first case all the time? That is, overwrite `.\Destination` instead of copying into it?

Comment: Can you clarify? you want to copy the contents of "source" in to "destination"? and not copy the folder "source" into "destination"?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The "destination" folder may not exist, so I want it to be created if it doesn't exit.

Comment: It may be worth considering [robocopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) as an alternative. You can still call it from powershell if you need to. It will handle the `if exists` issue easily and wont require you to force-ably recursively delete your destination either, which comes with its own dangers.

Comment: Closely related SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47964451/45375

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So the problem is that this:

```
Copy-Item -Force -Recurse foo bar
```

only works if `bar` does not exist and this:

```
Copy-Item -Force -Recurse foo/* bar
```

only works if `bar` exists. So to work around, you need to make sure `bar`
exists before doing anything:

```
New-Item -Force -Type Directory bar
Copy-Item -Force -Recurse foo/* bar
```

Answer (score 5):

Steven Penny's answer https://superuser.com/a/742719/126444 doesn't delete original content of the target directory, just appending to it. 
I needed to completely replace the target folder with content of the source and created  2 functions:

```
function CopyToEmptyFolder($source, $target )
{
    DeleteIfExistsAndCreateEmptyFolder($target )
    Copy-Item $source\* $target -recurse -force
}
function DeleteIfExistsAndCreateEmptyFolder($dir )
{
    if ( Test-Path $dir ) {
    #http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909167/how-to-quietly-remove-a-directory-with-content-in-powershell/9012108#9012108
           Get-ChildItem -Path  $dir -Force -Recurse | Remove-Item -force -recurse
           Remove-Item $dir -Force

    }
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $dir
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to copy contents of the "source" folder use

```
copy-item .\source\* .\destination -force -recurse
```

Comment: This only works if `destination` already exists.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that you Have the following structure of Directories

- root

  - folder_a

    - a.txt
    - b.txt
    - c.txt
  - folder_b

    - a.txt
    - b.txt

  In The root folder you can achieve the results you want by the following sequence of commands:

  `$files = gci ./folder_b -name`
  `cp ./folder_a/*.txt -Exclude $files ./folder_b`

Only c.txt will be copied